# Getting black images with robot.createScreenCapture on remote machine

Tags: windows, session, selenium, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a common problem getting black screenshots when the rdp session is closed. 
Didn't find any working answers for this problem.
I have java-selenium tests.
Code:

```
private void screenShot() {
    try {
        String newFileNamePath;  
        File directory = new File (".");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        Date date = new Date();

        newFileNamePath = directory.getCanonicalPath() + "\\test-output\\" + "logs\\" + "screenshot_" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".png";
        System.out.println(newFileNamePath);

        //Capture the screen shot of the area of the screen defined by the rectangle
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage bi=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(1920,1080));
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File(newFileNamePath));
        Reporter.log(newFileNamePath);   
    }       
    catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

When I run test via Jenkins on remote server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and rdp-session is **closed**, I get black screenshots. 
If the session is active - I get normal screenshots. 
But I need to make normal screenshot when the session is closed.

How can I make it? 
Any ideas?

VisualCron  and selenium.captureScreenshot() doesn't suit me.

Comment: Same problem here. On Win 2003 you could /console login and `tscon 0 /dest:console` for disconnect. Using VNC is a solution, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an alternative to using a VNC server, but I can't find it. So my answer is "Use VNC". Personally, I prefer [**UltraVNC**](http://www.uvnc.com/).

When installed, start your selenium Jenkins slave using a uvnc session and disconnect it.

The AWT Robot will work now.